# Hibernate 5.0.12 can't found column MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

Repository:

```
public interface SquadronTableRepository extends JpaRepository<SquadronTable, Long> {

    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT flightdata_id, Incoming_number, Date_of_flight, Flight_number, Departure, Arrival, Tail_number, KVS, VP, Deadline_cor_act, Cor_act_accepted, Risk_index, Talon_closure FROM flightdata WHERE AE=?1 ORDER BY flightdata_id DESC", nativeQuery = true)
    Collection<SquadronTable> findAllDesc(Byte AE);
}
```

This @Query can't find column AE in paratment. The problem that is I have name "AE" in MySQL, and I can not rename in MySQL due to the fact that I should keep backward compatibility. But Hiberate try to find small letters name "ae".
The exception is:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'ae' not found.

In @Entity class this field is:

```
@Entity(name = "SquadronTable")
@Table(name = "flightdata")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class SquadronTable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "flightdataId")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "AE")
    private Byte AE;
```

How can I told to Hibernate to look in "AE" column? Or another variant I just need to get from DB my model class with 2 conditions:

1. WHERE AE=5 or 4 or another Byte key - the number of department
2. and should be sorted DESC by id

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the decission it is:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl